# Implementing a function using a mux and no gates at all

Tags: multiplexer, karnaugh-map

Given the function \$f(w,x,y,z)=x'y'z'+w'xy' \$, where \$ '\$ means negation.
I was given this function from a mux \$2^3*3\$ - 8 inputs and 3 control lines.
In the original implementation \$y'\$ was connected to inputs 0,2,3,4, and the control lines were \$w,x,z\$ where w is the MSB, the rest are zeros.
I want to implement the same function using the same MUX, but without Not gates.
After trying everything I cant really point the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use another mux to get \$\overline{y}\$ like so

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbDz4g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

or just use a 16-input mux with all four control lines

Comment: That can work, but I have only one 8*3 mux.